# Glassfish v3.0.1 deployment suddently gone slow

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a smallish web application containing of two WAR files which I deploy to Glassfish 3.0.1 which I have used the Eclipse Glassfish plugin for quite a while to do.

Now today, this process has suddenly slowed very noticeable.  The WAR which contains a few JSP pages and static resources for the rest takes about 100 seconds to deploy, and the big one takes 274 seconds (as opposed to around 7 seconds before).

I've tried the following:

- Stop and start the server repeatedly.
- Reunzip Glassfish.
- Delete and recreate the Server Adapter in Eclipse.
- Use Real Jar Archives for Deployment in the Server Adapter.
- Unplug the network (might be some network resource timing out).
- Clean and redeploy the projects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the hot redeploy is filling up your perm gen space in memory.  It's gotten slower every time you redeploy.

If I'm correct, shutting down the server and restarting periodically should sort out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting glassfish has solved this for me in the past.